# Simple way to cut FLAC in Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, music, flac, music-management

I'm looking for the simplest way to cut music in Linux (Fedora 25).

It would be excellent if there's a command line option for doing something like:

```
cut OriginalSong.FLAC -start 4m30s -end 5m15s > CutSong.FLAC
```

And then convert it to MP3 if possible with something like

```
convert CutSong.FLAC > NewSong.MP3
```

to upload on the web.

Any suggestion is appreciated, it is intended to be simple and command line if possible.

Comment: `man flacsplt`. If it involves conversion anyway ,`ffmpeg` to do it in one step.

Comment: No such command in Fedora :(

Comment: Did you check to see if there is any packages in the repository for that tool, or flac tools?  If not, then do a bit of googling, download the source, and build it yourself?

Comment: Package `mp3splt` in Debian, [homepage](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net). Or just use `ffmpeg`, I'm sure that's available in Fedora.

Comment: Yeah what's the point of asking a question anyways when there's Google :)

Comment: @dirkt found it, just the name is different, plus it has GUI version on GTK

Comment: Please answer your own question with the correct package names for Fedora, so it gets documented and other people can look it up.

Comment: Best is to have the cue and use cuebreakpoints + shnsplit . cuetools and shntool are on Fedora